# Forgot MacBook password but recovery mode didn’t work

Tags: macbook-pro, password, recovery

So I just got my laptop back ate a year away from the office and forgot my pw.

Luckily there is easy advice online about power + cmd + R to get into recovery mode.

Trouble is from there I get stuck— the advice is

> Go to the Apple Menu at the top and click Utilities

But as you can see in the screen shot, there is no Apple many at the top with option UTILITIES — only “restart | shut down”.

I must be doing something wrong!

Yes I could reset from Apple ID, but it spent stay connected to my internet, probably because it’s a new network here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this a company owned laptop or your personal laptop? If its company owned its likely company managed and your help desk should be able to provide the recovery code to reset the password on the account.

If it's a personally owned laptop you can reset either using your Apple ID or obtain the recovery code from iCloud.

You may have to click "Forgot all passwords".

The disk must be encrypted with FileVault2 and it is likely a T2 based Mac.  Therefore you need to login with a local administrator account in order to get into Recovery Mode.  It's asking you for an account with administrative privileges.

Reboot normally and try to get it to ask about your Apple ID and then it will use your iCloud stored recovery key to reset your password.  But again, if it's managed by your IT administrators if the Mac is owned by your employer then you have to call them to reset the password, provide the recovery code.